# Node JS: chaining promises which are using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request-promise

I need to chain promises which are using request promises, so it is kinda chaining nested promises.

Imagine the code:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

function doStuff(){
  for ( let i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ){
    methodA();
  }
};

function methodA(){
  let options = {...};
  rp(options)
    .then(result => methodB(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

function methodB(resultA){
  let options = {uri: resultA};
  rp(options)
    .then(result => methodC(resultA, result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

function methodC(resultA, resultB){
  //some calculations
};
```

In doStuff I need to wait for result of all ten executions of methodC and collect them into array. I have tried to chain it like that:

```
function doStuff(){
  for ( let i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ){
    let promiseA = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(methodA());
    });
    let promiseB = promiseA.then(result => methodB(result));
    let promiseC = promiseB.then(result => methodC(promiseA.result, result));
    Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC]);
  }
};
```

But for sure it won't work, because in methodA and methodB we have HTTP requests which are asynchronous. Therefore, result in promiseB is undefined.

It means, the question is: **how to chain promises, if they have nested promises?** (and how to collect result in the end?)

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Chaining promises also not much of the help, as 1 is returned prior array of AB's, but desired result is vice versa:

```
function methodA(){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Resolved A');
            resolve('A');
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });

    return promise
        .then(result => methodB(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodB(resultA){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Resolved B');
            resolve('B');
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });

    return promise
        .then(result => methodC(resultA, result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodC(resultA, resultB){
    return resultA + resultB;
}

function doStuff() {
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        promises.push(methodA());
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    });
    return 1;
}

console.log(doStuff());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using jQuery deferred or promise to wait for multiple $.post calls to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164037/using-jquery-deferred-or-promise-to-wait-for-multiple-post-calls-to-finish)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. The promises there don't rely on each other.

Answer (score 2):

Each of your functions needs to return their promise:

```
function methodA(){
    let options = {...};
    return rp(options)
        .then(result => methodB(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodB(resultA){
    let options = {uri: resultA};
    return rp(options)
        .then(result => methodC(resultA, result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodC(resultA, resultB){
    //some calculations
}

function doStuff() {
    let promises = [];
    for ( let i = 0; i <= 10; i++ ){
        promises.push(methodA());
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(...)
}
```

**Edit:** I created a test example, which creates promises in `methodA` and `methodB`. Each promise lasts some amount of time from 0 to 2 seconds. It seems to be working:

```
function methodA(){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Resolved A');
            resolve('A');
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });

    return promise
        .then(result => methodB(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodB(resultA){
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Resolved B');
            resolve('B');
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    });

    return promise
        .then(result => methodC(resultA, result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function methodC(resultA, resultB){
    return resultA + resultB;
}

function doStuff() {
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        promises.push(methodA());
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        console.log(results);

        return 1;
    });
}

doStuff().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of doing `methodC` in `methodB`

Comment: True, but in my infinite wisdom I removed that to make it simpler :D

Comment: @Felix Kling I see you posted the same exact answer like one second after mine, and then deleted it. I was going to give you an upvote!

Comment: Well, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Maybe just a faster connection. I upvoted one of your other well written answers :)

Comment: tried that, but didn't work, sorry. still the same: doStuff ends prior methodC

Comment: Please check my edit. I created a test example which seems to work. Please run it in your browser console.

Comment: huh, strange thing happened. when I start server, on the first execution  result is empty, but on the second one - as expected.

Comment: see correction. even from the browser it works not from the first execution :( I mean, not always, but from time-to-time

Comment: my code (and I have no reputation to start chat, so sorry for that chat alike thing here).

Comment: @FrankModica  see that: 1 is returned prior array: `your initial code
function doStuff() {
    let promises = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        promises.push(methodA());
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    });
    return 1;
}

console.log(doStuff());`

Comment: If you want `1` logged after the other promises, simply add that logic inside: `Promise.all(...).then( // return 1 here )`. Or you can create a promise that resolves `1`, and push that promise into the array of promises that is passed to `Promise.all`.

Comment: @FrankModica, it is easy to try. if you put `return 1;` into `then` section, then undefined is printed, therefore, doesn't seem to be an option (as everything running in promise is a non-blocking operations and leads method to continue). that's the whole point. how to wait till it is done?

Comment: You also have to return the promise that comes from `Promises.all`. See my update.

Comment: @FrankModica, mm, that's about writing in the console and yes, it will write to the console in the correct order. but writing code is not about logging something to console. I want to assign value of executing `doStuf()`into variable and render that on UI. and, keeping in mind modular architecture and loosely coupling, routing/rendering is one module and calculation is different. e.g.: I've got a request, I calculate in isolated module, I get a result, I render that and only rendering module knows about calculation. I hope it is clear now: `doStuff()`have to return variable on execution.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. `doStuff` is a completely isolated and independent function. You can put it anywhere. Once you call it, instead of logging out the result in the `.then`, you can do whatever you want with it.  If you assign the result to a variable then it can be rendered.

Comment: @FrankModica, sorry, I was wrong. I have used xml2js ES5 version using callbacks and this is why chain was broken. I have switched to `xml2js-es6-promise` and now whole chain works fine. Many thanks for help!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question please mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Frank_Modica is the way to go.

Just want to add that if you enable `async/await` you could do it like this. But it does require `Babel` or `Typescript`:

```
async function myMethod() {
    const options = { }
    try {
        const result_a = await rp(options)
        const result_b = await rp({ uri: result_a })
        const result_c = ...
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    await myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It has to be lightly changed to:

```
Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB, promiseC]).then([promiseD]);
```

Also in the functions itself it has to be a return statement to make them chained. For the request itself, just add: {async: false}

Also it can be used:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
function methodA () {
    return runSequence(
        'promiseA',
        'promiseB',
        ['promiseC1', 'promiseC2'],
        'promiseD',
        callback
    );
}
```

Comment: @KirillLinnik, but have you tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request ?

Comment: it won't help neither, as chaining has nested promises because of request-promise inside. it means, I can chain, but because of nested promises, chain is executed outside the function return